# How can I forbid minimization in AwesomeWM 4.2?

Tags: awesome-wm

I use awesomewm 4.2 and I would like to keep windows from ever minimizing.  I have experimented with the `request::activate`, `raised`, and `lowered` signals and none of them fire when clients minimize themselves.  Ideas?

Comment: This isn't an answer, just a reference to the [issue](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/pull/2429) regarding this. Uli answer is currently the only way to do it. Of course it is an after-the-fact workaround and can potentially have side effects if other code is connected to the minimization signal. The long term plan is to be able to block such requests just like focus stealing, geometry changes and size hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I would expect this to work:

```
client.connect_signal("property::minimized", function(c)
    c.minimized = false
end)
```